# PHP parse error on line 6...seems likes it's something simple I'm overlooking.

Tags: php, sql

I'm am having an issue creating a simple login form. Can anyone explain why SQL says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$username' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Easy Grade 2000\login.php on line 6" and how to fix it?

Thanks

```
<?php

include 'connect.php'

// username and password sent from form 
$username = $_POST['u_name']; 
$password = $_POST['p_word']; 

$sql="SELECT * FROM $db_name WHERE u_name='$username' and p_word='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the semicolon after the include:

```
include 'connect.php';
                     ^---- :)
```

Comment: Aww man, now I have another problem...sorry to be a bother. I am getting this error---> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Easy Grade 2000\login.php on line 13. Wrong Username or Password. I put a dummy username and password in the table, but I just don't know where I went wrong here.